# How to Ensure Instant Email Sending Through PHP

Tags: php, sendmail

I have made a Registration Page for the Users to get registered and When User Will be registered a confirmation Email will be sent to the User Email Address. But The PHP mail() function some times sends email instantly and some times after several minutes and The Mail also goes to the SPAM Box. I have seen so many forums where Mail is sent instantly and does not go to SPAM Box and goes directly to Inbox.

How can I solve my above mentioned Problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can't speed up the process of sending mail with just PHP. As for the spam issue, this is one of many issues with the PHP `mail()` function. You can take a look at the headers of the emails that are being marked as spam and usually it should give some kind of indication as to why it's spam. Also, check the headers in the email you're sending. As I said, the `mail()` function can be tough to work with. Go with a better solution:

[PHP Mailer](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) or [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your lag: you could save the message in a database and use a cron every minute to send the mails which are in the queue. The user will usually get the message within 1 minute.

Regarding your SPAM problem: use a SaaS like http://www.sendgrid.com

Answer (score 0):

Mailchimp would be better for this : http://mailchimp.com/

Comment: arguable not an answer to the question _how_ :-)